# How to set data types for request params in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Is there a way to validate request params in AWS Api Gateway, by setting data types for values, in **Query String**, **Request Paths** and **Request body**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by creating a model against your expecting JSON data. Please have a look on below documentation on how to create a model in API gateway.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-create-model.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html